# Error Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

So i download some challenge edutools and after i run the challenge , i get error , i was install jdk java, sdk java, kotlin sdk , and gradle  why i can get error  i use , java jdk version

> openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)

and i use gradle version 6.2.2

> Gradle 6.2.2

and this is full output of my gradle version

[image: gradle-version]

and this is my full output of error on my intelejit idea

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Answer (score 3):

If I read https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10248 correctly, this is an incompatibility with some Gradle versions and some JVM versions. I had a similar issue with Android SDK. You basically have two options:

1. Downgrade your JVM to e.g. 1.8 - or install an alternative JVM
2. Upgrade Gradle to >= 6.5

In my case, I set the JVM version to 1.8 and it worked flawlessly afterwards.

Comment: hey can you solve my problem , about java instalation

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains Academy projects work on Java 11. Java 13
[is not supported yet](https://support.hyperskill.org/hc/en-us/articles/360038633072-How-to-install-and-run-IDE-and-EduTools-Plugin-for-Java-and-Kotlin-).

Please make sure that JDK 11 is selected in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle**.

Also, ensure that the project has JDK 11 selected as Project SDK in **File | Project Structure**.

You can download OpenJDK 11 from [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when using either Mac(macOS Big Sur) and Ubuntu(20.04 LTS) and I was able to resolve it by doing the following:

Go to **/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** file in your RN project. Find the line that starts with **distributionUrl** and change the gradle version into **gradle-6.4.1-all.zip**.

FROM:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**5.4.1**-all.zip

TO:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**6.4.1**-all.zip

See sample illustration below:

[image: RN-gradle-wrapper]